# Automatic breakpoint in XCode 6?

Tags: c, xcode6

I'm writing a simple shell program for a C assignment where we have to handle pipes, file redirection, etc. For some reason, XCode seems to be including an automatic breakpoint somewhere in the assembly code. This only occurred after I started using execvp() to call the command line program (such as ls), rather than system(). This breakpoint does not occur if I compile this using gcc. Does XCode automatically include breakpoints when the program is being replaced by another?

The whole program is here: http://pastebin.com/QX8xPkqB
And a screenshot of the breakpoint: [image]